# PyAudio and Audition CS6 recording different sample values

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

**What shall be evaluated and achieved:**

I try to record audio data with a minimum of influence by hard- and especially software. After using Adobe Audition for some time I stumbled across PyAudio and was driven by curiosity as well as the possibility to refresh my Python knowledge.
As the fact displayed in the headline above may have given away I compared the sample values of two wave files (indeed sections of them) and had to find out that both programmes produce different output.
As I am definitely at my wit`s end, I do hope to find someone who could help me.

**What has been done so far:**

An M-Audio “M-Track Two-Channel USB Interface” has been used to record Audio Data with Audition CS6 and PyAudio simultaneously as the following steps are executed in the given order…

- Audition is prepared for recording by opening “Prefrences/ Audio Hardware” and selecting the audio interface, a sample rate of 48 kHz and a latency of 250 ms (this value has been examined thoughout the last years as to be the second lowest I can get without getting the warning for lost samples – if I understood the purpose correctly I just have to worry about loosing samples cause monitoring is not an issue).
- A new file with one channel, a sample rate of 48 kHz and a bit depth of 24 bit is opened.
- The Python code (displayed below) is started and leads to a countdown being used to change over to Audition and start the recording 10 s before Python starts its.)
- Wait until Python prints the “end of programme” message.
- Stop and save the data recorded by Audition.

**Now data has to be examined:**

- Both files (one recorded by Audition and Python respectively) are opened in Audition (Multitrack session). As Audition was started and terminated manually the two files have completely different beginning and ending times. Then they are aligned visually so that small extracts (which visually – by waveform shape – contain the same data) can be cut out and saved.
- A Python programme has been written opening, reading and displaying the sample values using the default wave module and matplotlib.pyplot respectively (graphs are shown below).
- Differences in both waveforms and a big question mark are revealed…

Does anybody have an idea why Audition is showing different sample values and specifically where precisely the mistake (is there any?) hides??

**some (interesting) observations**

a)  When calling the pyaudio.PyAudio().get_default_input_device_info() method the default sample rate is listed as 44,1 kHz even though the default M-Track sample rate is said to be 48 kHz by its specifications (indeed Audition recognizes the 48 kHz by resampling incoming data if another rate was selected). Any ideas why and how to change this?

b)  Aligning both files using the beginning of the sequence covered by PyAudio and checking whether they are still “in phase” at the end reveals no – PyAudio is shorter and seems to have lost samples (even though no exception was raised and the “exception on overflow” argument is “True”)

c)  Using the “frames_per_buffer” keyword in the stream open method I was unable to align both files, having no idea where Python got its data from.

d)  Using the “.get_default_input_device_info()” method and trying different sample rates (22,05 k, 44,1 k, 48 k, 192 k) I always receive True as an output.

**Official Specifications M-Track:**

bit depth = 24 bit
sample rate = 48 kHz
input via XLR
output via USB

**Specifications Computer and Software:**

Windows 8.1
I5-3230M @ 2,6 GHz
8 GB RAM
Python 3.4.2 with PyAudio 0.2.11 – 32 bit
Audition CS6 Version 5.0.2

**Python Code**

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import time

formate = pyaudio.paInt24
channels = 1
framerate = 48000
fileName = 'test ' + '.wav'
chunk = 6144
# output of stream.get_read_available() at different positions

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=formate,
                channels=channels,
                rate=framerate,
                input=True)
                #frames_per_buffer=chunk) # observation c

# COUNTDOWN
for n in range(0, 30):
    print(n)
    time.sleep(1)

# get data
sampleList = []

for i in range(0, 79): 
    data = stream.read(chunk, exception_on_overflow = True)
    sampleList.append(data)

print('end -', time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(time.time())))

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

# produce file
file = wave.open(fileName, 'w')
file.setnchannels(channels)
file.setframerate(framerate)
file.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(formate))
file.writeframes(b''.join(sampleList))
file.close()
```

Figure 1: first comparison Audition – PyAudio
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfsmN.jpg)

Figure 2: second comparison Audition - Pyaudio
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMu7W.jpg)